# SQL query not functioning on online server, working on local server

Tags: php, mysql

I'm facing a problem here.
I have a search sql query that works on  my local server, but not online. What could be the problem? I've checked the versions, it seems to be all ok on both sides...
Here is the code:

```
$nume='%'.$_GET['term'].'%';

$stmt = $db->prepare("
SELECT `p`.`id_produs`,
   CASE WHEN `p1`.`id_produs` IS NULL THEN
       `p`.`nume_produs`
   ELSE
       CONCAT(`p1`.`nume_produs`, ' de ', `p`.`nume_produs`)  
   END `nume_produs`, 
   `p`.`exista_sortiment`, 
   `p`.`sortiment_produs`
FROM `produse` AS `p` LEFT JOIN `produse` AS `p1`
ON `p`.`sortiment_produs` = `p1`.`id_produs`
WHERE `p`.`exista_sortiment` = '0'
AND (`p`.`nume_produs` LIKE :nume
    OR
    `p1`.`nume_produs` LIKE :nume 
    OR CONCAT(`p1`.`nume_produs`, ' de ', `p`.`nume_produs`) LIKE :nume
    )");

//$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `produse` WHERE `nume_produs` LIKE '%".$nume."%'");
$stmt->execute(array('nume'=>$nume));
$continut = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Masa');
```

If anyone has any ideas, ițd be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: i dont see any error... I simply dont get any results..

Comment: you have a different db online (which probably is empty) and therefore no result is the correct result

Comment: this is not the problem. there are entries in the db

Comment: hjave you tried running the query directly against the DB via phpmyadmin or other

Comment: Does a simple query works? Does problem happens for this particular query? Also check the data that it have the results having your particular condition.

Comment: PDO does not throw exceptions by default. You need to tell it to in the constructor.

Comment: this happens for every query, no matter what. Ive tried in phpmyadmin both local and online. Works local, doesnt online. there are no errors whatsoever

Comment: after all i've read here, i still insist on my previous answer -> there is no matching entry for this query in your db. tried to upload your local db (and use the same testcase)?

Comment: There are more than enough entries in the db, both local and online. Ive even tried with the full name, same problem.

Comment: solved the problem. The exista_sortiment was 1 on every entry.

Comment: as i said (i know how long one can spent on "errors" like this) ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try executing this query on phpMyadmin to see if on both local and on the server query works properly

Answer (score -1):

Please check **Collation** on Structure.

Sometimes due to difference of "Collation", it was happening.